# Stack Overflow error when instantiating a new Class

Tags: c++, class, stack-overflow

I have a "Class" class that has a string name and an Array of "Student" objects. The "Student" class has a name and has "Grades". The "Grades" class is a array of doubles.

In the main class, I create a Grades object and a Student object. I test some of the functions with it and it all works well:

```
int main(){

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    Grades test = Grades ("5 - 90.0 85.0 95.5 77.5 88.0");
    cout << test.toString() << endl;
    cout << "\nSum  = " << test.getSum() << endl;
    cout << "Num grades  = " << test.getNumGrades() << endl;
    cout << "Low grade  = " << test.getLowGrade() << endl;
    cout << "High grade  = " << test.getHighGrade() << endl;

    Student stu = Student("Billy Bob", "5 - 90 85 95.5 77.5 88");
    cout << stu.toString() << endl;
    cout << "\nSum  = " << stu.getSum() << endl;
    cout << "Average  = " << stu.getAverage() << endl;
    cout << "Average after dropping low grade  = " << stu.getAverageMinusLow() << endl;
    cout << "Low grade  = " << stu.getLowGrade() << endl;
    cout << "High grade  = " << stu.getHighGrade() << endl;

}
```

However when I add the line:

```
Class testClass = Class("Comp Sci 1", 3);
```

and then run the program, it has a Stack Overflow error.
"First-chance exception at 0x0033EAB7 in Gradebook.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x003D2000)."

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
 Is it because there are too many objects and that each object is a member of another object? Is there a way to "delete" my "test" and "stu" objects that were created before this line?

Here is my "Class" constructors for reference:

```
class Class{
    private:
        string name;
        Student studentList[100];
        int numStudents;

    public: Class(string className, int numStudents1);
            Class();
}

Class:: Class(string className, int numStudents1){
    name = className;
    numStudents = numStudents1;

}
Class:: Class(){
    name = "";
    numStudents = 0;
}
```

Does this error show up because my "studentList" Student array in the Class object is not instantiated in the constructors?

Comment: Why not `Class testClass("Comp Sci 1", 3);`? Other that that, you will have to show more code in order to find out what is wrong.

Comment: You appear to be confusing stack and heap instantiations. Right now you're causing unneeded copy actions because of how you assign them.

Comment: Also, why pass number of students when you have decided that students are 100? Use a vector instead and have only as much students as you need. This way students will not be put on the stack by on the heap, which might be the reason why you get the overflow.

Comment: What you did creates one Class and then copies that to testClass, which is unnecessary. But there is other stuff wrong with your implementation strategy.

Comment: Thank you @ddriver. This worked. I will definitely look more one stack vs heap allocations in C++. I cannot use a vector since my teacher is not allowing it. Otherwise, I would have definitely used it.

Comment: I'm adding my answer as a comment since it's not 100% sure if you're getting that because of the `Student` objects size: take a look at the difference between stack allocations and heap allocations in C++. A heap allocation is usually performed with the `new` operator

Comment: Show us the `Student` constructor.

Comment: If your not allowed to use new, malloc or vector, there is only a global declaration left which uses the heap. Hacking around with stacksize is then also not allowed I would guess.

Comment: Did your teacher tell you to pass grades as a string literal? And in the very constructor of `Student`? You would typically create the student and then add grades in some kind of container. If so, your teacher might be in need of some teaching himself :)

Comment: And to not use vector? I mean is he teaching C++ or masochism? People definitely need to learn to use containers like vector first and then, for whatever reason, learn how to to create massive flat objects.

Comment: I think the teacher is laying the foundation for the understanding of the structure of programs.

Comment: @Surt - I will add an answer to elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Every variable declare in a function gets located on the stack, variable declared outside functions are static variable and use the [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).

```
Class testClass("Comp Sci 1", 3);

int main(){
```

This is also bad in some ways but not as much as causing stackoverflow.

Comment: ...? Heap and static data segment are not equivalent.

Comment: @milleniumbug a lot of that is going around. Appears to be confusion sparked by some particular implementation.

Comment: Heap is part of data segment (at least wikipedia agrees with that ... but you shouldn't believe all that is on wiki).

Answer (score -1):

That design is just plain out wrong.

You should have a vector or similar container inside `Student` to hold all grades, and a similar container inside `Class` to hold all students. You say your teacher doesn't allow you to use vector, which doesn't make a lot of sense seeing your level, but maybe he expected you to create your own container class? Again, you don't seem to be quite there yet, so it is a kind of a paradox.

Your problem is you have enough storage allocated in a Class for 100 students, and those 100 students might have a lot of grades, so the class might end up being massive, too big to put on the stack, which is why it overflows. This way the class plus the students plus the grades create one big chunk of "flat" memory. And when you use that form of instantiation `Class testClass = Class(...)` without compiler optimizations it creates not one but two objects, just to assign the latter to the former. Fixing the class constructor (you should fix the other as well) might fix the overflow problem, but it doesn't fix your design problems.

It is much simpler and recommended good practice to have such big constructs as a `Class` not flat in memory. Having it flat is actually more complex but might have other advantages (such as performance or memory efficiency) and is still safe to use with dynamic allocation, but in your case you are not interested in top notch efficiency, but with understanding and therefore having a good design.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, creating a student with the grades is wrong, especially passing grades as a string literal. If that was a real program you have to use in practice, how are you going to create new students in the beginning of the year with all their grades, if the grades are yet to come? Your Student class constructor should only pass a name for the student, and instead you should have a `addGrade()` member funciton.

And what about that Class object pre-allocating a static array with length 100? If you only have 3 students, then there is 97 students worth of memory wasted. And what if you need to have more than 100 students? Your program crashes. Which is why you should use a container and have only as many students as you need. And I can only assume the same horrendous thing is happening inside the Student class. Those type of "techniques" are typically used in old C code, which might be what your teacher is plagued by, but is certainly not recommended for teaching modern C++.